# Time complexy: growing list in nested for-loops

Tags: python, time-complexity, big-o

In this code:

```
test = [1] * 10
result = []
for i in test:
    if not result:
        result = [i,i,i]
    else:
        new_result = []
        for j in result:
            for k in range(3):
                new_result.append(i + k)
        result = new_result
```

The outer loop runs n times.
The inner loop, if I'm not wrong, runs 3^n

The Big O of this algorithm is 3^n * n. Am I right?

Comment: It's just `O(3^n)`. As sum: `1 + 3 + 3^2 + ... + 3^n = O(3^n)`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's just `3^n`. if you try this after your execution:

```
print(len(result)) #result: 59049
print(3**len(test)) #result: 59049
```

So yes it grows exponentially relative to the size of `n` as the output of `result` will grow as follows by each iteration:

```
3
9
27
81
243
729
2187
6561
19683
59049
```

I used `timeit` to print out the execution time as `n` grows

```
n = 10 # Time:  0.020012678000000002
n = 11 # Time:  0.057932331000000004
n = 12 # Time:  0.15807880600000002
```

You see where it's going in terms of time.

here is the code I used:

```
import timeit
test = [1] * 12
result = []
start = timeit.default_timer()

print(test)
for i in test:
    if not result:
        result = [i,i,i]
        print(result)
    else:
        new_result = []
        print(len(result))
        for j in result:
            for k in range(3):
                new_result.append(i + k)
        result = new_result

stop = timeit.default_timer()

print('Time: ', stop - start)
```